# Python Kivy - Make Ellipse adjust to available space

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create [this simple background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRgzm.png).
This is what I have so far:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class BaseLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyWindow(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(BaseLayout())


class MyApp(App):
    # 'Global' Variables
    size_x = 220*1.3
    size_y = 250*1.3

    def build(self):
        return BaseLayout()


MyApp().run()
```

And my .kv-file:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<BaseLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: (app.size_x, app.size_y)
    size_hint: (None, None)

    #:set bg_color hex('#262626')
    #:set topBar_color hex('#1c1c1c')
    #:set bt_color hex('#4d4d4d')

    AnchorLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1

        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: topBar_color
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'right'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            padding: 10, 10

            Label:
                size_hint: (1, 1)
                # size: (25, 0)

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: bt_color
                    Ellipse:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

    Label:
        size_hint_y: .9
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: bg_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

I'm looking for a way to have the circle always adapt to the height of the bar at the top (and of course it should be an actual circle and not the stretched ellipse it is now).
The window is not meant to be resized, but I want to be able to control the widget with the size_x and size_y variables, so I cannot just enter some absolute values.
The size_hint for the height is correct, but I could not find a way to just set the width of the circle to its height.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of your `kv`:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<BaseLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size: (app.size_x, app.size_y)
    size_hint: (None, None)

    #:set bg_color hex('#262626')
    #:set topBar_color hex('#1c1c1c')
    #:set bt_color hex('#4d4d4d')

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        size_hint_y: .1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: topBar_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        Widget:
            size_hint: None, 1
            width: self.height
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: bt_color
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

    Label:
        size_hint_y: .9
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: bg_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
```

This uses a `Widget` with `size_hint: None, 1` to make it the height of the parent, and allow the `width` to be set as `width: self.height` to make a square `Widget`. The drawn `Ellipse` using that size will be a circle. Note that, in general, the `AnchorLayout` only works well with one child (additional children will be drawn on top of each other).